# JavaScript: Augmenting types - Purpose of "return this"

Tags: javascript

I'm reading JavaScript - The Good Parts currently. So I've dealing with augmentation of types. 
I understand the motivation and the implementation. But if I look at the code ...

```
Function.prototype.method = function(ident, funct) {
    this.prototype[ident] = funct;
    return this; // No idea. For what?
};
```

... then I don't understand the purpose of the return.
I have put the return in comments. That doesn't have an effect. It functioned anyway.

My complete code:

```
Function.prototype.method = function(ident, funct) {
    this.prototype[ident] = funct;
    return this;
};

Date.method('sayHello', function() {
    alert(new Date().toString());
});

var myDate = new Date();

myDate.sayHello();
```

So what it is for?

Comment: Probably to allow method chaining. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Typically this is done so you can chain method calls, so called "fluent interfaces":

```
obj.method().anotherMethod().yetAnotherMethod()
```

E.g.:

```
'string'.toUpperCase().substr(2).repeat(3)
```

In case of the string, *another* new string is being returned instead if `this`, but you get the idea why it's useful.